# ConfigurationManager gets data from where?

Tags: c#, configurationmanager

C# Project.

I have a project (i didnt write it) and in this project i have a config file (app.config). Actually there is nothing there but default lines.
And in this project i have cs file with the line:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnect"].ConnectionString;
```

And everything works fine! How?! As far as i know ConfigurationManager takes data from the local app.config. I dont understand from where ConfigurationManager takes this connection string because app.config has only default lines. Are there any places where CM can take it? Also i searched through Machine.config (just in case) and there wasnt any line like my connection string.

Comment: In the app.config is there something called `connectionStrings`? Did you try to search for `DbConnect` in app.config? Can you share the app.config contents here?

Comment: Are there any other `.config` files? connections strings can also be stored in external config files.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, i've searched through the file, nothing like connectionStrings and DbConnect
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7pxbfj8lvf76q4l/app.config?dl=0

Comment: @Nkosi, no any other config files in this project

Comment: Is the project a class library? If is, check the app.config of other projects.

Comment: @bruno.almeida, yes, it is dll. Does ConfigurationManager search through another projects' config files?

Comment: @Adventurer, yes, it uses others projects config file

Comment: Is there any web application  project, console application project, or Windows form project in your solution? ConfigurationManager reads values from the configuration file from the application which is a startup project using this class library.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya. Yes, in the solution there are many projects and one of them contain this library. It is asp.net mvc project with web.config file. Still web.config doesnt contain info like i am searching for. Here is the web.config file https://www.dropbox.com/s/lqyilh228pml70u/Web.config?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Search for "DbConnect"...

Also you should search for search for appsettins.json file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration

Comment: Did this. Nothing was found. Can config files be imported from another projects? I have some custom dlls in my project and does configurationManager aggregate all config files in one and search though it?

Comment: Try this, go to your output folder and look for YourAssembly.exe.config, open it with a notepad and look for the connection string...

Comment: Tried. No, it doesnt aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the file which your project actually uses at runtime at "Your_Project_folder\bin\Debug" path, if you set up your proejct in a normal way.
The file name could be App.Config or Your_Project_Name.exe.config

Hope that this is helpful.